# Casting a void pointer to a struct and initialise it

Tags: c

Casting a void pointer to a struct, i want to initialise the struct component. i used the code below . 
i want to initialise and access test->args structure. How can i do it?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct ctx {
    int a;
    int b;
    void *args;
  };
struct current_args {
    char *a;
    int b;   
  };


int main()
{
    struct ctx current_ctx = {0};
    struct ctx *test=&current_ctx ;
    struct current_args *args = (struct current_args *)(test->args); 
    args->a=strdup("test");
    args->b=5;
    printf("%d \n", (test->args->b));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Well, you *do* cast the pointer, but it's already initialized to `NULL`, so dereferencing it is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some problem for code snippet as below: actually, `test->args` is a NULL, it pointers to nothing. Then `args->a` will cause error like segmentation fault.

```
struct current_args *args = (struct current_args *)(test->args);//NULL  
args->a=strdup("test");
```

To initialise and access `test->args` structure, we need add a `struct current_args` instance, and assign it to `test->args`,such as

```
int main()
{
    struct ctx current_ctx = {0};
    struct ctx *test=&current_ctx ;

    struct current_args cur_args= {0};//added
    test->args = &cur_args;//added

    struct current_args *args = (struct current_args *)(test->args);
    args->a=strdup("test");
    args->b=5;
    printf("%d \n", (((struct current_args*)(test->args))->b));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any other alternate way to do this or must we map a struct like that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean the following

```
struct ctx current_ctx = { .args = malloc( sizeof( struct current_args ) ) };
struct ctx *test = &current_ctx ;

struct current_args *args = ( struct current_args * )( test->args ); 
args->a = strdup( "test" );
args->b = 5;

printf( "%d \n", ( ( struct current_args * )test->args )->b );

//...

free( current_ctx.args );
```

If your compiler does not support the initialization like this

```
struct ctx current_ctx = { .args = malloc( sizeof( struct current_args ) ) };
```

then you can substitute this statement for these two

```
struct ctx current_ctx = { 0 };
current_ctx.args = malloc( sizeof( struct current_args ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not properly initialize your struct instance.

`struct ctx current_ctx = {0};` sets all members of current_ctx to 0, so the struct is empty and the `args` pointer is invalid.

You need to first create an args instance and let current_ctx.args point to it like so:

```
struct args current_args = {a = "", b = 0};
struct ctx current_ctx = {a = 0, b = 0, args = &current_args};
```

Just remember: Whenever you want to access a pointer, make sure that you have initialized it before.